# Extra space with counted line number?

Tags: shell, string, wc

I count the number of lines of my file with this command on OSX:

```
nl=$(wc -l < ~/myfile.txt)
```

Say, `nl` turns out to be 100. Now, I wish to use the result `nl` in another command, but weirdly,

```
echo 1-$nl
```

gives me `1- 100` instead of `1-100`.

## Demo

```
cv me$ nl=$(wc -l < ~/Desktop/cap.xlsx)
cv me$ echo $nl
104
cv me$ echo 1-$nl
1- 104
```

[image]

[image]

Why does this happen? How may I get `1-100`?

Comment: What OS are you on? I can't reproduce this on my Debian.

Comment: @terdon I am on OS X. Please see the updates.

Comment: Weird. Make few tests to narrow the problem: 1) set value directly `nl=100`; 2) try different delimiter, not `-`; 3) put double quotes around expression `echo "1-$nl"`; 4) use `printf` instead of `echo`

Comment: @Sibbs; I either cannot reproduce it. What output do you get when quoting `echo $nl` as `echo "$nl"`.

Comment: @Janis I can't format that properly here. Please see the screenshot above.

Comment: @jimmij Done. Please see the 2nd screenshot above.

Comment: @Sibbs; Okay, so you confirmed that your version of `wc` will produce leading spaces in your case. Those spaces are retained in the assignment `nl=$(...)` - See my answer below for possible workarounds.

Answer (score 6):

As POSIX defined, the output of `wc` shall contain an entry for each input file of the form:

```
"%d %d %d %s\n", <newlines>, <words>, <bytes>, <file>
```

But the output file format pseudo `printf()` string differs from the System V version of `wc`:

```
"%7d%7d%7d %s\n"
```

POSIX didn't require leading spaces to be added, so it's free for implementation to do what it want. There are different implementations of `wc`, at least with OSX and `wc` from heirloom tools chest, it added leading spaces to output.

```
$ /usr/5bin/wc -l /tmp/file
      3  /tmp/file
```

GNU wc also add leading spaces when reading from standard in and without any options:

```
$ cat file | wc
  5       5      65
```

To remove all leading spaces, in POSIX shell:

```
set -f
set -- $nl
nl=$1
set +f
```

Note that this approach assume that variable only contain leading or trailing spaces, no spaces in the middle, like *a b*.

Answer (score 4):

`wc` implementations may produce leading spaces; this may also be depending on whether (and how many) options are used (GNU `wc`, for example, won't produce spaces if, as in your case, exactly one option is used). Those spaces are retained in the assignment `nl=$(...)`. To remove the spaces, as a workaround, you could use either of:

```
nl=$(wc -l < ~/myfile.txt | awk '{print $1}')
```

or

```
nl=$(awk 'END{print NR}' ~/myfile.txt)
```

or

```
nl=$(wc -l < ~/Desktop/cap.xlsx)
nl=$(echo $nl)
```

or (but see @cuonglm's comment below for *heirloom*'s version of `wc`)

```
nl=$(wc -l < ~/Desktop/cap.xlsx)
nl=${nl##* }
```

Comment: @cuonglm; Thanks for spotting that; I changed the shell regexp now from `nl=${nl## *}` to `nl=${nl##* }`.

Comment: It still fail with heirloom `wc`, it produce trailing spaces, too. So you still remove the entire variable.

Comment: The heirloom `wc` produces **trailing** spaces? - Okay. I'll leave that variant still as one option. With your comment here the folks now know that in heirloom context they should apply one of the other suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Simpliest workaround (in bash or any other POSIX shell):

```
nl=$(wc -l < ~/myfile.txt)
nl=$(($nl))
```

`$((...))` in standard `sh` is for arithmetic expansion, so the result will always be only the number itself.  Note that if `wc -l` produces no output (like when the file can't be read), that will yield `0` instead of an empty string.

`$((nl))` would also work in `bash` but is not guaranteed to by POSIX as `$nl` doesn't contain a numerical constant, and in practice doesn't work in `yash` for instance.

You can also do it all at once with:

```
nl=$(($(wc -l < ~/myfile.txt)))
```

Which has the benefit of preserving the exit status of `wc`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative without the problem of spaces (POSIX):

```
$ sed -n '$=' ~/myfile.txt
```

Captured in a variable:

```
$ nl=$(sed -n '$=' ~/myfile.txt)
$ echo "1-$nl-"
1-100-
```

Note that sed counts the last line even if it doesn't end in a newline character (as it should in a properly formatted text file). More generally, sed may fail to print the number of newline characters in non-text files.

---

Another alternative:

```
$ nl=$(grep -v . ~/myfile.txt | tr '\n' 'x')
$ echo "1-${#nl}"
1-100
```

Note that grep will also print invalid characters (additionally to newlines) in the locale used.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Why is *sed counts the last line even if it doesn't end in a newline character* not enough for you? (hmmm, for reasonably clean text files)

Comment: Sorry, I had overlooked that part.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler quick fix to remove leading and trailing spaces would be to cast it as integer.

```
echo 1-$nl
```

to

```
echo 1-$(($nl))
```